# Quickblox Android SDK: Using the or custom operator in custom object query

Tags: android, quickblox

We need to use the `or` operator with Quickblox custom object module in Android, but no records are returned.

Below is what tried so far:

`myArray` is an array of `String[]` containing the parameters to be compared

**Trial 1:**

```
QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();

requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);

requestBuilder.or("tag_number",  myArray );

QBCustomObjects.getObjects("CollectionNum", requestBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl()
{
@Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             QBCustomObjectLimitedResult coresult = (QBCustomObjectLimitedResult) result;
             ArrayList<QBCustomObject> co = coresult.getCustomObjects();
             Log.d("Records: ", co.toString());
         } else {
             Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
         }
     }
});
```

-> This is triggering onComplete function, but is returning NO result
-> Gives warning in eclipse:
The argument of type `String[]` should explicitly be cast to `Object[]` for the invocation of the `varargs` method or(String, Object...) from type `QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder`. It could alternatively be cast to Object for a `varargs` invocation

**Trial2:**

```
QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();

requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);

requestBuilder.or("tag_number",  toObjectArray(myArray) );

QBCustomObjects.getObjects("CollectionNum", requestBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl()
{
@Override
    public void onComplete(Result result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
             QBCustomObjectLimitedResult coresult = (QBCustomObjectLimitedResult) result;
             ArrayList<QBCustomObject> co = coresult.getCustomObjects();
             Log.d("Records: ", co.toString());
         } else {
             Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString());
         }
     }
});


public static Object[] toObjectArray(Object array) 
{
    int length = Array.getLength(array);
    Object[] ret = new Object[length];
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        ret[i] = array[i];

    return ret;
}
```

-> This is NOT triggering onComplete
-> This is NOT returning results.

Notice the difference is that whether am sending `myArray` or `toObjectArray(myArray)`.

Please advice, is there a working example for using or operator in custom object in Android?

Comment: Can you provide a request log as well?